# What's the major difference between the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore and MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore driver

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-2.0

I just want to choose one of the MySQL provider for ASP.Net Core 2.0. So far, all the tutorials i get on the web are for Pomelo provider, though i've configured MySQL official provider as on a test project. At this point of time, both looks same to me. Can anyone point out a specific reason to choose one of them ?